# Totally disconnected space is 0-dimensional

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X\neq \emptyset$ be a compact, perfect metrizable space. (This is a segment of an exercise, I do not know if every property will be involved in the proof)

I want to proof that $X$ is totally disconnected implies that $X$ is $0$-dimensional.

For that I have to give a basis $\mathcal{B}$ where every element is closed and open.

I tried to study the sets in $X$ which are closed and open, to construct a basis. But until now, I was not able to give such a set, besides the trivial $\emptyset$ and $X$.

$X$ is totally disconnected. So $\{x\}$ is closed. But $\{x\}$ is not open as $X$ is perfect.

I know that the clopen sets can not be finite, as this would contradict that every singleton is not open.

I do not know if this "strategy" will eventually lead to a proof.

Do you have a hint?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only that $X$ is totally disconnected, locally compact, and Hausdorff. Let $x\in X$, and let $U$ be an open nbhd of $x$; we want to show that $x$ has a clopen nbhd contained in $U$. $X$ is locally compact, so $x$ has an open nbhd $V$ such that $\operatorname{cl}V\subseteq U$ and $\operatorname{cl}V$ is compact. If $V$ is clopen, we’re done.

Otherwise, the total disconnectedness of $X$ implies that for each $y\in\operatorname{bdry}V$ there is set $H_y$ such that $x\in H_y$, $y\notin H_y$, and $H_y$ is clopen in $\operatorname{cl}V$. Then each $H_y$ is closed in $X$, so $\{X\setminus H_y:y\in\operatorname{bdry}V\}$ is an open cover of $\operatorname{bdry}V$. And $\operatorname{bdry}V$ is compact, so there is a finite $F\subseteq\operatorname{bdry}V$ such that

$$\operatorname{bdry}V\subseteq\bigcup_{y\in F}(X\setminus H_y)\,.$$

Let $H=\bigcap_{y\in F}H_y$; clearly $x\in H$, and $H$ is clopen in $\operatorname{cl}V$. Moreover, $H\cap\operatorname{bdry}V=\varnothing$, so $H\subseteq V\subseteq U$. Thus, $H$ is closed in the closed set $\operatorname{cl}V$ and open in the open set $V$, so $H$ is clopen in $X$ and in particular is a clopen nbhd of $x$ contained in $U$.

Comment: Thank you. Would the proof become simpler, if we use that $X$ is compact, instead of the more general proof where $X$ is just locally compact? This proof seems very nontrivial to me.

Comment: @Cornman: You’re welcome. I don’t immediately see any way to simplify it.

Comment: I don't see why the total disconnectedness of $X$ implies the existence of $H_y$. I understand you are using that $\overline{V}$ is disconnected, but this just implies  the existence of a clopen set in $\overline{V}$ separating this set but maybe contains both $x$ and $y$

Comment: @HFKy: In a compact Hausdorff space quasicomponents coincide with components, so if the space is totally disconnected, the quasicomponents are singletons, and it follows immediately that distinct points can be separated by clopen sets.